# selectize causes keyboard to appear on Android

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, selectize.js

On Android, when the selector is touched, the keyboard input appears. I suspect this is because the generated input is of type="text".

**How can I prevent this from happening? If the user is choosing from a drop-down list, it does not make sense for the keyboard to appear.**

I'm implementing selectize as an Angular module [angular-selectize](https://github.com/machineboy2045/angular-selectize), but I checked with the developer and the issue is not specific to the angular wrapper.

Here is my code:

```
        <selectize  ng-model="filters.min_bedrooms" 
                    options="[
                            {title:'0', id:0},
                            {title:'1', id:1},
                            {title:'2', id:2},
                            ]">
        </selectize>
```

Which generates this markup:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="" style="width: 4px; opacity: 0; position: absolute; left: -10000px;">
```

Comment: And the question/desired effect is?

Comment: The question is updated. Why is that happening and how can I prevent it?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to prevent the user can type in this field? .. So what sense does it make to use `selectize.js` when their main objective is the combination of `text` & `select`? Please correct me if I understand it wrong.

Comment: You understand right. But selectize is able to make a normal select also. This use case seems clearly supported based on the documentation... For example there is an option to turn OFF the create feature.

Comment: Something like this will help?... http://jsfiddle.net/gmolop/3m57zru4/

Comment: @gmo that looks like the right idea. Thanks. Perhaps consider submitting it as an answer?

Comment: @SDP Creator here – this isn't what selectize is designed to do. If you're just interested in select decoration, I'd chose something else / simpler.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue, where I want the user to select a value but not enter any new values, and the keyboard always shows up when you tap on the dropdown on an iPad. I've solved it by this:

```
$('#myDropDownId').selectize({
    create: true,
    sortField: 'date'
});
$(".selectize-input input").attr('readonly','readonly');
```

Basically what happens is, the input gets focus when you click/tap on the dropdown, and that is what shows the keyboard. By setting readonly to false, the input no longer gets focus.

I've tested this on an iPad Mini 2 in Safari and Chrome.

Comment: [I personally used `.prop('readonly', true)` instead of `.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: If you don't want users to enter new values, why use `create: true`?

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
$(".selectize-input input").attr('readonly','readonly');
```

Also worked:

```
$(".selectize-input input").prop('readonly','readonly');
```

Comment: Just to add, in Angular 8, call above jquery inside `ngAfterViewInit`

Answer (score 0):

Quoting http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/:

> **Selectize** is the hybrid of a textbox and `<select>` box.

It is not a pure `<select>` UI widget equivalent; it is not a dropdown-only widget. If you want to use it as such, you will need to disable/hide the `<input>` element while keeping the whole directive working.

Comment: Can you expand on what you are suggesting? Or maybe mention how it could be done?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to prevent the user can type in this `text` field...
<sup>(ergo, no keyboard on focus, but still will be able to select one of the dropdown options)</sup>

So, as you said this is exactly what you want, and as far as I know this is not possible to do it with default options, it occurs to me to do this disabling the input field <sup>(readonly)</sup> on `focus event`, and turn it back again when loose focus (`blur event`).
With this, the user is able to select another tag after the first one.

Check out this example...

```js
var tags = [{
    id: '1',
    value: 'first'
}, {
    id: '2',
    value: 'second'
}, {
    id: '3',
    value: 'third'
}, ];

// initialize the selectize control

var $select = jQuery('#test').selectize({
    create: true,
    closeAfterSelect: true,
    options: tags,
    valueField: 'id',
    labelField: 'value'
});
var selectize = $select[0].selectize;

selectize.on('focus', function () {
    jQuery('.readonly').find('input').attr('readonly', true);
});

selectize.on('change', function () {
    selectize.blur();
});

selectize.on('blur', function () {
    jQuery('.readonly').find('input').attr('readonly', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.0/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.0/css/selectize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<label>test
    <input class="readonly" name="test" id="test" />
</label>
```

It's an approach, but I think this could be enough depending on your needs.
<sup>(or at least, point you in the right direction)</sup>

<sup>*[JSFiddle file](http://jsfiddle.net/gmolop/3m57zru4/) in case the embed snippet don't work as expected.*</sup>