# Disable typing on selectize

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

As the title, on selectize, how can I disabled typing except Backspace key.

It will be allowed to:

- Select item on dropdown.
- Delete selected items.

It will NOT be allowed to:

- Type or add any new items.

I have read the API document but I can't found the solution. Any suggestions.

Here mine:

```
var $select = $('#tags').selectize({
        maxItems: 5,
        persist: false,
        createOnBlur: true,
        create: true,
    });
```

**UPDATE:**

I found the solution by my own

```
$select[0].selectize.$control_input.on('keydown', function(e) {
        var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
        if(key == 8 )
            return true;
        else
            e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: The solutions listed above didn't work But this is work!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30087408/20175904

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the way you did it works, the proper way to prevent item addition is to use `create: false`:

```
var $select = $('#tags').selectize({
    maxItems: 5,
    persist: false,
    create: false
});
```